# Do windows vista and windows 7 coexist with Win XP in the same HD?

Tags: windows

Can it be installed in 3 different partitions without conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. I'd recommend using the technique outlined by this blog:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, without problem.

If you want to do this, I would recommend you install them in order of release date, earliest to newest.

I have not tested Windows 7 in multi boot, and you may be able to get away with installing XP, 7 then Vista, however I still always recommend the above as best.